# Proving stochastic dominance for hypergeometric random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

I suspect that the following statement is true:

**Statement:** *Let $f$ be a nondecreasing function, and let $X_k$ be a hypergeometric($2n$, $k$, $n$) random variable, where $n\ge1$ is a constant integer. Then $\mathbb{E}[f(X_k/n)]$ is nondecreasing as $k$ increases.*

(Here, $X_k$ is the number of "good" balls out of $n$ balls taken uniformly at random, all at once, from a bag containing $2n$ balls, $k$ of which are "good".)

This is equivalent to verifying whether $\frac{X_{m+1}}{n}\succeq\frac{X_{m}}{n}$ (and, obviously by extension, $X_{m+1}\succeq X_{m}$) in terms of first-degree stochastic dominance (Levy 1998, *Stochastic dominance*). This means that the distribution function of $X_{m+1}$ (or the probability that $X_{m+1}\le j$) is less than or equal to that of $X_m$ for each $j$ in the interval [0, *n*].

However, I find that proving this is quite tedious, as the distribution functions have a non-trivial form. It's not enough to say that $\mathbb{E}[X_k/n]=k/(2n)$ is increasing with *k*, since this does not imply the statement given above as stochastic dominance does.

Is there an existing proof of this statement or a generalization of it, or existing results that could make proving it less tedious?

Comment: Is $X_{k}$ the number of green balls in a sample without replacement of $k$ balls from $n$ green balls and $n$ red balls? If so, $X_{m+1}\succeq X_{m}$ seems obvious.

Comment: @Henry: Here, $X_k$ is the number of "good" balls out of $n$ balls taken uniformly at random, all at once, from a bag containing $2n$ balls, $k$ of which are "good".  I have added a clarification to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial argument that $X_{k+1}\succeq X_{k}$:

Let's suppose your bag has $k$ good balls, $1$ intermediate ball, and  $2n-k-1$ bad balls, so $2n$ in total.  $n$ balls are taken without replacement and $X_k$ counts the number of good balls taken and $Y_{k+1}$ counts the number of good or intermediate balls taken.

Clearly $Y_{k+1} \ge X_k$, and $\mathbb P(Y_{k+1} \ge x) \ge \mathbb P(X_{k} \ge x)$ for all $x$.

Since $Y_{k+1}$ has the same distribution as $X_{k+1}$, this implies $\mathbb P(X_{k+1} \ge x) \ge \mathbb P(X_{k} \ge x)$ for all $x$ and so $X_{k+1}\succeq X_{k}$.

Comment: Also thank you for your recent help on stackoverflow on efficient R code